# DX - Custom Plugin Install

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

Usually DX CLI plugins are installed via `sfdx plugins:install <plugin-name>`

The examples provided from `sfdx plugins:install --help` list these:

```
$ sfdx plugins:install myplugin
$ sfdx plugins:install https://github.com/someuser/someplugin
$ sfdx plugins:install someuser/someplugin
```

If I write something I want to use internally, would `sfdx plugins:install <https or ssh link to repo>` work?

Or is it a better practice to host on an internal registry and provide consumers of the plugin some command to use like `npm install git://<address>`?

Any tips from admins or devs in similar situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly keep the code on your private git repo and have you users install using below commands

```
git clone <https/ ssh link of repo>
```

Then users will need to cd into the directory of the project `cd <PluginFolderRoot>`

After that they can execute the below command

```
sfdx plugins:link <pluginname>
```

The other alternative approach is to use `sfdx plugins:install <github link>`. In this case  the node modules for the plugin gets installed at the location `$HOME/.local/share/sfdx/node_modules/<Plugin root folder>`

You will need to cd into same and run `sfdx plugins:link <pluginname>`

Comment: Awesome, marked this as the answer. Thanks @MohithShrivastava

Comment: You mean you upvoted it ? There is a green mark to mark as answered !

Comment: forgot that, just marked it an answer not upvote

Comment: you can also, if building this and having another version installed use `sfdx plugins:link <path to root of project>` to link and use the plugin. EX: `sfdx plugins:link ./`

Answer (score 2):

At work we have a plugin hosted on a private npm registry and are using GitLab for source control. After trying many different things, I found that providing the url is the best practice for installing private plugins:

```
sfdx plugins:install https://your-git-whatever.com/namespace/project-name.git
```

Doing it this way will allow you to run `sfdx update` and it will update the base `sfdx` package as well as any plugins you have installed. Just make sure you can authenticate to the url that you provide.

Comment: Great tip, thank you!